# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN) when setting UIDatePicker's date

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exception

I am receiving the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN) when I am trying to set the date of my UIDatePicker on the third line. Sometimes the error appears consistently when I run my application. Sometimes the error does not show up at all.

```
startTimePickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:
                     CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 216,
                                self.view.frame.size.width, 216)];
[startTimePickerView addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(datePickerDateChanged:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
startTimePickerView.date = [NSDate date];
```

Any help on this issue would be appreciated as I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Is your `startTimePickerView` an IBOutlet referring to your storyboard?

Comment: It is not an IBOutlet. I am just initializing it programmatically.

Comment: Add an exception-breakpoint and check if anything is nil, especially the DatePicker when the error occurs